# How to pass List on Stepper in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating App using Stepper but there is an error when I pass List in Stepper

Something Like: The named parameter "steps" isn't defined

my Code :

```
class Stepper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StateStepper createState() => _StateStepper();
}

class _StateStepper extends State<Stepper> {

  List<Step> my_steps = [
    new Step(title: Text("Step 1"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 2"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 3"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 4"), content: Text("Some Content")),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Util App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
       child: Stepper(steps:my_steps),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: change the name of your `Stepper` class, like `MyStepper` for example or anything else

Comment: Ohh got the point, Thanks @pskink 

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyStepper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _StateStepper createState() => _StateStepper();
}

class _StateStepper extends State<Stepper> {

List<Step> my_steps = [
    new Step(title: Text("Step 1"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 2"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 3"), content: Text("Some Content")),
    new Step(title: Text("Step 4"), content: Text("Some Content")),
];


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Util App"),
      ),
      body: Container(
       child: Stepper(steps:my_steps),
       ),
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) is a class which is in `flutter/material package`, hence avoid using the reserved name or used class name in your app.